# Installing PyX package on Mac for python 2.7

Tags: python, macos, pyx

Is there a simple instruction for installing PyX package on the Mac OSX (10.6.8) for python( 2.7)?

> python setup.py install

worked fine (copied the Library), however adding "import pyx" fails.

Comment: The exact error message ``import pyx`` produces, including the stack trace, would be helpful.

Comment: last line: IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: *including the stack trace*, please.

Comment: Pardon me, where do I find that information?

Comment: When you run your program, and it gives you the error, it spits a lot of text in the terminal, with file names, line numbers, and lines of code from these files. That's the stack trace. It's very helpful to know not only what the error message is, but also at what place the error happened.